# jquery functions not working when data called after page load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

what I'm going to ask might not be possible, I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I set up my website so that there is only one actual webpage (index.php). All the html and page content is stored in a php script. So I simply post for the data depending on the which page they want to view and .html() it within my page template. It all works great, just how I wanted.

The problem is that any jquery functions that use element tags that are within the html that I call from the server and render after the page load no longer work. I'm not really sure why this is happening. Does jquery render into memory all the page elements on the page load, so that ids and classes added post-page load are not considered?

Any insight, or different ways to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @joe , mostly your issue is you are not using live for the elements added after loading dom , regular bind will work only for page load , please use live and you should be all good

Comment: Also this approach is bad for SEO. And accessibility eg. Devices with JavaScript turned off. A much better way would be to load all the pages on the first go and then just manipulate client side. Im assuming it's not very many pages.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but it isn't the type of site that I would bother using if javascript is turned off. That and for this particular instance I want I'd rather not store the content client side to begin with. I could load all the data on the page load as opposed to when they click the particular section of the site, and that would use less posts, but still an initial one that would require javascript. and seo isn't really a concern for the type of website it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you could use .delegate() which has more benefits than .live()

http://api.jquery.com/delegate

That allows you to attach events to elements on page load and those created after which is what you're doing with .HTML()

With anything that you're doing that is not event bound you should run all your jquery stuff right after you replace things on the page everytime. Not just on page load.

Put all of it into a function so you can call it easily.

Comment: so are you saying that all i have to do is instead of using a .click function, I use .live('click' instead?

Comment: @joe thats true. that should do it

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot! I've used live('click') in the past as opposed to .click but I never really understood the difference.

Comment: The difference is that it binds it to the global object and tells it to look for matching nodes each event. It is an extremely expensive bind and should be used sparingly. Usually `delegate()` is a better future-proof event observer because you can choose the most appropriate parent instead of the top level parent.

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution

http://api.jquery.com/live/

anything you add after you load dom should use live or delegate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain you've determined the exact problem you're having. There are probably 2 problems going on here, layering to create the impression you've come to:

1) jQuery .bind() and its shortcut functions like .click(), .hover() etc bind at the time they're called, not continuously like CSS rules.

So for example this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.stuff').click(function(){alert('Hi');}
});

<div class=stuff>Say hi</div>
```

Will not work on new HTML inserted into the document after the page first loaded, because `$(document).ready()` fires when the body tag closes/when jQuery finishes initializing, whichever is second, and not again when you load your new HTML.

A naive answer is to use .live()

```
$('div.stuff').live('click', function(){alert('Hi');}
```

This will cause new HTML loaded into the page to fire if it contains a div with class stuff, because jQuery listens for live events on the body tag, which remains in place, and then matches the tag that fired the event to see if it matches the selector. That second step is a little expensive, and with a lot of live selectors your page will respond to events slowly. That's bad.

The better answer is to load the new HTML, and bind. Maybe something like this:

```
function pageBinds() {
    $('div.stuff').click(function(){alert('Hi');}
}

$(document).ready(pageBinds);

function loadPage() {
    $.ajax(...)
    pageBinds();
}
```

This gets you performant binds that respond to the loaded content.

You might consider unbinding before loading new content, as leaving the existing events bound can pollute jQuery depending on the event and the browser, but it would take a lot of events and a lot of page loads to have a major impact on a desktop (a smartphone might feel it a little faster). Unbinding would be more involved, though.

2) Script tags in innerHTML'd content are ignored.

This confounds many an ASP.Net programmer using UpdatePanels, which do exactly what you're coding here in PHP. Any script tags in the page you load may as well not be there - the browser just tosses them. In order to run script with your HTML, you need to explicitly execute it using eval() or a couple other more complex tricks.

You can resolve this by loading any content as script separator html. So you use a separator character sequence, have the AJAX call you built separate the incoming string with .split(), eval the script portion, and innerHTML the HTML.